# How to convert navigator.sendBeacon to a fetch call?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api, httpresponse, sendbeacon

I've seen quite a [few docs/articles](https://xgwang.me/posts/you-may-not-know-beacon/#fetch-keepalive) suggesting that `fetch` with the `keepAlive` flag is equivalent to `sendBeacon`.

```
fetch('/track', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: getData(),
  keepalive: true,
});

// Same as 
navigator.sendBeacon('/track', getData());
```

However, `sendBeacon` actually returns a `Promise<Boolean>`. According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#return_values):

> The sendBeacon() method returns true if the user agent successfully queued the data for transfer. Otherwise, it returns false

Is there a way to mimic this with a fetch call? A fetch call always returns a `Promise<Response>`. So the return value is not identical. Is there a way to make a fetch call return `true` or `false` based on the same "data queue" heuristic as `sendBeacon`? Traditionally `sendBeacon` is not concerned with the response, only whether or not the data was emitted or not.